# Android BLE BluetoothGattCallback not work

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want my ble service run in background even App is closed, that I can still read data. So I used "startService" instead of "bindService". I initialize & connect ble, but I have no idea why my BluetoothGattCallback doesnt work? Here is my [code](http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/i2Ymwut4Bj).
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your onCharacteristicRead() method is empty. You have to read the received amount of bytes in this method.

Comment: I write log in onCharacteristicRead() ,but my logcat still empty.