# BluetoothGattCallback seems no response in "startService"

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am making a BLE application and I follow the example in [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html) but I want to receive the ble data in background even the App is closed so I changed "bindService" to "startService" to start my ble service.

However, I found that after I initialize & connect the device, the callback is no response, which means it does not call the function in the callback even the connection state changed or gatt discover. I found a similar post in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836739/android-ble-bluetoothgattcallback-not-work) but it seems no one provide solution to him.

How can I solve this? Why the callback works by calling "bindService" to start the service but not by calling "startService" to start the service?

My service code is [here](http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/DAAGw99EkR)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're calling connectGatt() on the main thread, as some phones require this for the callback to work.

Also be warned that on some phones the gatt callback can fire on a different thread before connectGatt() has returned with the gatt object.